# Jetpack Compose MutableSharedFlow one shot events

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

in my viewmodel I have a function that sends a login request to a server, when successful i want to update a SharedFlow and using this trigger a navigation to another screen

```
class loginViewModel: ViewModel() {

private val _authToken = MutableSharedFlow<AuthToken>()
val authToken: SharedFlow<AuthToken> = _authToken

fun login() {
...loginRequest

.onSuccess {
 _authToken.emit(value)}
}
```

in my nav graph I set up the viewmodel like so

```
private fun NavGraphBuilder.addLogin(navController: NavController) {
composable(AuthenticationScreens.Login.route) {

    val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val authToken by loginViewModel.authToken.collectAsState()

        LoginScreen(
        authToken = authToken,
        viewModel = loginViewModel,
        navigateToDashboard= {
            navController.navigate(Dashboard.Dashboard.route)
        }
    )

  }
}
```

i then do an if check in my loginscreen to navigate to the other screen when the SharedFlow updates

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
authToken: AuthToken,
viewModel: LoginViewModel,
navigateToDashboard: () -> Unit) {

if (authToken.isNotBlank()) {
navigateToDashboard()}
}
```

The code fires but is called constantly even when i've navigated to the next screen, causing lots of flickering and bad UI. Is there a different way I'm supposed to handle navigation events like this or a way to have the composable only read the value once when required?

Answer (score 1):

So i've figured out a way to do this but I still feel this isn't fully correct, I set the shared flow back to it's default state after navigating. If anyone has a more concise approach please let me know

```
  LaunchedEffect(key1 = authToken) {
    if (authToken.token?.isNotBlank()) {
        navigateDashboard()
        viewModel._authToken.emit(AuthToken("", 0))
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found this a solid way to consume one shot (hot flow) events?