# Ui state not working correctly in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using MutableStateFlow [UI State](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#stateflow) in jetpack compose. I am not getting proper flow of my UI event. In UI state there is **Empty**, **Loading**, **Success** and **Error** state. I setup a **Empty** state when I initialise a variable. When I am starting to call api before that I am trigger **Loading** state. On that basis I am triggering **Success** or **Error** event.

**Note:** I am not adding imports and package name. If you want to see full code please click a name of class you will redirect to my repository.

[**MainActivityViewModel.kt**](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/viewmodel/MainActivityViewModel.kt)

```
class MainActivityViewModel(private val resultRepository: ResultRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val stateResultFetchState = MutableStateFlow<ResultFetchState>(ResultFetchState.OnEmpty)

    fun getSportResult() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.IsLoading
            val result = resultRepository.getSportResult()
            delay(5000)
            result.handleResult(
                onSuccess = { response ->
                    if (response != null) {
                        stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.OnSuccess(response)
                    } else {
                        stateResultFetchState.value = ResultFetchState.OnEmpty
                    }
                },
                onError = {
                    stateResultFetchState.value =
                        ResultFetchState.OnError(it.errorResponse?.errorMessage)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[**MainActivity.kt**](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/ui/screen/MainActivity.kt)

```
internal lateinit var networkConnection: NetworkConnection

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        networkConnection = NetworkConnection(application)
        setContent {
            SportsResultTheme {
                SetupConnectionView()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SetupConnectionView() {
    val isConnected = networkConnection.observeAsState()
    if (isConnected.value == true) {
        NavigationGraph()
    } else {
        NoInternetView()
    }
}

@Composable
fun NoInternetView() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(getBackgroundColor()),
        contentAlignment = Center,

        ) {
        val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.nointernet))
        LottieAnimation(
            composition,
            iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever
        )
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SetupMainActivityView(
    viewModel: MainActivityViewModel = koinViewModel(),
    navigateToNext: (state: String) -> Unit,
) {
    Scaffold(topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)) },
            backgroundColor = getBackgroundColor(),
            elevation = 0.dp
        )
    }, content = { padding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(getBackgroundColor())
                .padding(padding),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Button(onClick = {
                viewModel.getSportResult()
            }) {
                Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.get_result))
            }
        }
    })
    when (val state = viewModel.stateResultFetchState.collectAsState().value) {
        is ResultFetchState.OnSuccess -> {
            navigateToNext("loading $state")
        }
        is ResultFetchState.IsLoading -> {
            LoadingFunction()
        }
        is ResultFetchState.OnError -> {}
        is ResultFetchState.OnEmpty -> {}
    }
}


@Composable
fun LoadingFunction() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(getBackgroundColor()),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
}
```

I am adding my navigation graph so you will clearly see what I am trying to do.

[NavigationGraph.kt](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/ui/screen/navigation/NavigationGraph.kt)

```
@Composable
internal fun NavigationGraph() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = ScreenRoute.Home.route) {
        composable(ScreenRoute.Home.route) {
            SetupMainActivityView { state ->
                navController.navigate(ScreenRoute.Result.route + "/{$state}")
            }
        }

        composable(
            ScreenRoute.Result.route + "/{state}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("state") { type = NavType.StringType }
            )
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            ResultScreen(backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("state").orEmpty())
        }
    }
}
```

**[ResultScreen.kt](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/ui/screen/ResultScreen.kt)**

```
@Composable
fun ResultScreen(state: String) {
    Log.e("TAG", "ResultScreen: $state" )

}
```

**Actual Output**

when you click on `Button` it started **Loading** screen. After **Loading** screen my **Button** screen appears than my **Result** Screen appears. You can see in my [video](https://youtube.com/shorts/U3enIvCKLgg?feature=share).

```
Button Screen -> Loading Screen -> Again Button Screen -> Result Screen.
```

**Expected Output**

```
Button Screen -> Loading Screen -> Result Screen.
```

My Github project [link](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult). Can you guys guide me what I am doing wrong here. Many Thanks

UPDATE

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SetupMainActivityView(
    viewModel: MainActivityViewModel = koinViewModel(),
    navigateToNext: (nearestResult: ArrayList<NearestResult>) -> Unit,
) {
    Scaffold(topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)) },
            backgroundColor = getBackgroundColor(),
            elevation = 0.dp
        )
    }, content = { padding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(padding)
                .background(getBackgroundColor()),
            contentAlignment = Center
        ) {
            when (val state = viewModel.stateResultFetchState.collectAsState().value) {
                is ResultFetchState.OnSuccess -> {
                    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                        navigateToNext(state.nearestResult)
                    }
                }
                is ResultFetchState.IsLoading -> {
                    LoadingFunction()
                }
                is ResultFetchState.OnError,
                is ResultFetchState.OnEmpty -> {
                    ActivityContent(viewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

After doing this my [ResultScreen](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/ui/screen/ResultScreen.kt) calling twice. Is it normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During loading you overlap the button view with the loading view, but when you succeed you remove the loading view, so the button view appears for the transition.

Depending on the expected behavior, you can move your `when` inside the `content`, and display content only on empty/error - it might make sense to leave the option to click back to cancel the request.

```
content = { padding ->
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(padding).background(getBackgroundColor())) {
        when (val state = viewModel.stateResultFetchState.collectAsState().value) {
            is ResultFetchState.OnSuccess -> {
                LaunchedEffect(Unit){
                    navigateToNext("loading $state")
                }
            }
            is ResultFetchState.IsLoading -> {
                LoadingFunction()
            }
            is ResultFetchState.OnError, is ResultFetchState.OnEmpty -> {
                YourContent()
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Or add `LoadingFunction()` inside `ResultFetchState.OnSuccess`, so that this view doesn't disappear from the screen during the transition.

```
is ResultFetchState.OnSuccess -> {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit){
        navigateToNext("loading $state")
    }
    LoadingFunction()
}
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159644/composable-is-recomposing-endlessly-after-flow-collect/71159855#71159855) for why calling `navigateToNext` as you do is unsafe and why I've added `LaunchedEffect`.

Comment: thanks for replying to me. Can you please guide me why do you replace `column` with `Box` ?

Comment: @vivekmodi your column should be instead of `YourContent`, `Box` is just a container to apply some modifiers used for all children

Comment: Great thank a million. You are great. I really appreciate it. My code is working fine.

Comment: Hey @PhilDukhov my [ResultScreen](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/ui/screen/ResultScreen.kt) is calling twice when I click on button inside this [MainActivity](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/ui/screen/MainActivity.kt). Is it normal ?

Comment: @vivekmodi sure, read first part of the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159644/composable-is-recomposing-endlessly-after-flow-collect/71159855#71159855) which I've mentioned in this answer

Comment: I think i got it now. Thank you so much. I have another issue regarding back navigation. Can you please look into this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73072904/11560810)