# App Crash when observing a Live Data in Jetpack Compose Composable due to memory issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, kotlin-stateflow

I have one `Composable` which has one `Callback` function which is responsible to perform some action based on value it is observing in `ViewModel`. The Composable looks like.

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navigateToSecondScreen: () -> Unit
) {
    val stateFlow by viewModel._screenState.collectAsState()
    val apiSuccess by viewModel.apiCallSuccess.observeAsState(initial = false)
    if(apiSuccess){
        navigateToSecondScreen()
    }
  }
```

The Composable is called in this way

```
MyComposable(viewModel = myViewModel, navigateToSecondScreen = {
                // action for navigation
})
```

The `apiSuccess` is a LiveData inside `ViewModel` whose value is updated after Api Call is success in this way

```
    private val _sendingOtpSuccess: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
        val sendingOtpSuccess: LiveData<Boolean> = _sendingOtpSuccess
        viewModelScope.launch {
                    myRepository.makeApiCall(argument = argument).collect { responseState  ->
                        when (responseState) {
                            is ResponseState.Loading -> {
                                
                            }
                            is ResponseState.Success -> {
                                _sendingOtpSuccess.value = true
                                    
                            }
                            is ResponseState.Error -> {
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I got this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: co.myProject.compose, PID: 10904
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 10383376 byte allocation with 6291456 free bytes and 8530KB until OOM, target footprint 47887792, growth limit 50331648
```

With this above code when Api Call is Success the Composable keep continue observing and after some time App gets crashed showing memory issue. What is going wrong here ? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Check if [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69491725/3585796) helps you.

Comment: Hey Thanks it is working, but need to check what made it working. Thank you so much

Comment: My answer is clear about the reasons: during transition from one screen to an other one, `MyComposable` is recomposed multiple times(around each frame), and each time you call `navigateToSecondScreen` which creates an other navigation route - this recursively leads to a memory leak. Please upvote the answer if it helped your.

Comment: oops... But I still have the issue of when screen navigating to back it open again the secondScreen after pressing back

Comment: Your `apiCallSuccess` contains `true` when you're coming back, that's why it's happening. It can be solved in many ways. You can remove the route from the navigation stack using `popUpTo`, as showed in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-to-composable) - then your view model will be freed and a new one will be created when you navigate to the same route. An other option is using a shared flow as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71036376/3585796) - this will make sure you only react once on an event.