# How to use SharedFlow in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

With state flow I can use

```
val items by myViewModel.items.collectAsState()
```

I suppose shared flow cannot be used this way. Are shared flows even applicable for Compose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you can collect it as state as any other `Flow` - with an initial value:

```
flow.collectAsState(initial = 0)
```

This state will have the last value emitted by the flow during the time of view being presented, or the initial value. I'm not sure this makes much sense, though.

But you can also use it as a way to deliver events that require a one-time response, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71036376/3585796).

Comment: Can we collect this Flow from inside another ViewModel?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I'm not sure I got the question. technically you can pass flow to an other view model function, and collect it there using viewModelScope, but I'd say it's cleaner to use some other class with shared scope between your view models, e.g. repository

Answer (score 14):

SharedFlow should be used for one-shot events(navigation, toast, etc... ).

So this is the way to collect a SharedFlow:

```
@Composable
fun <T> Flow<T>.collectAsEffect(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    block: (T) -> Unit
) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        onEach(block).flowOn(context).launchIn(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's a real code example of how to call this in Compose?

Comment: Modelling events using a once-off-mechanism usually is an antipattern: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodel-one-off-event-antipatterns-16a1da869b95

Answer (score 3):

Just use LaunchedEffect with repeatOnLifecycle.
Without repeatOnLifecycle, your flow will be collected even when the app is in the background.

Eg.

```
@Composable
fun YourFunction() {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
                sharedFlow
                   .collect { /* doSomething */ }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, I suggest using channels instead of shared flows, if the flow is collected in only one place as it has built-in buffer so you will not miss any event.

You can find more explanation in Philipp Lackner video about One-Time Events in Jetpack Compose