# Compose Snackbar not appearing on repeated error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar

I am new to jetpack compose and is trying to show an error snackbar whenever the error message I am observing is not null.

```
Scaffold(scaffoldState = scaffoldState) {
        LaunchedEffect(errorMessage) {
            if (errorMessage != null) {
                scope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(errorMessage)
                }
            }
        }
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
              //some ui components inside here
        }
    }
```

The issue in the above code is that, the first time the error message changes from null to a particular message it appears fine. However on a repeated user action that produces the same error message it's not coming again.

P.S - I know this is happening due to placing the `errorMessage` as key inside the `LaunchedEffect`. My doubt is that, is there a different approach to achieve what I want?

Comment: Can you show me how the errorMessage is defined and observed?

Comment: I [prefer using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71036376/3585796) for such jobs.

Comment: @MustafaIbrahim I have defined error message as a string which is part of the pageUiState. This uiState is observed and collected from the viewModel.

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because the `LaunchedEffect` will run again just in case the `errorMessage` has changed.
What you can do is:

```
LaunchedEffect(errorMessage) {
   if (errorMessage != null) {
        resetErrorMessage() // reset errorMessage
        scope.launch {
            scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(errorMessage)
        }
   }
}
```

The `resetErrorMessage` must set the `errorMessage` to null, so the `LaunchedEffect` will run again, but since you're checking if it is not null, nothing will happen. But as soon you receive a new error message, the `LaunchedEffect` will be executed again.

Answer (score 1):

I see some issues with the answer provided above

First, there is no need of relaunching a coroutine inside a `LaunchedEffect` (which will execute a suspend function also) , so we can remove the `scope.launch` from the `LaunchedEffect`

Second, if we use `resetErrorMessage()` before `.showSnackBar` happens, we will emit a null (empty) message. We should reset the error message after the `showSnackbar` has been executed.

```
LaunchedEffect(errorMessage) {
   if (errorMessage != null) {
        scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(errorMessage)
        resetErrorMessage() // reset errorMessage
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to support repeated messages/errors and don't show one message/error multiple times. Recomposition will be called just ones

1.Create a smart delegate that removes the value after reading. It is the main logic

```
class OnceReadDelegate<T>(private var value: T? = null) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T? {
        val currentValue = value
        value = null
        return currentValue
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, newValue: T) {
        value = newValue
    }
}
```

2.Create a Message class that manages our text and type of message

```
class Message {
    var payload by OnceReadDelegate<String?>()
    var type: MessageType = MessageType.Error

    companion object {
        fun create(text: String?, messageType: MessageType = MessageType.Error) =
            Message().apply {
                payload = text
                this.type = messageType
            }
    }
}

sealed class MessageType {
    data object Regular : MessageType()
    data object Error : MessageType()
}
```

3.My example of state class with our Message class

```
data class SettingsPageState(
    val listWidgetState: List<WidgetViewState> = emptyList(),
    val listAgeFormat: List<AgeFormat> = emptyList(),
    val message: Message? = null,
    val isLoading: Boolean = true,
    val isEmpty: Boolean = false
)
```

4.My example of updatin the state with a new message

```
mutableState.update { previousState ->
    previousState.copy(message = Message.create(exception?.message))
}
```

5.And finally Composable function how to how Snackbar

```
@Composable
fun SettingsScreen() {
    ...

    LaunchedEffect(state.message) {
        val text = state.message?.payload
        if (!text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            //your method to show snackbar
            onShowSnackbar(text , null)
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

It is all)

Answer (score 0):

Dirty hack:

So the idea is to restart the side-effect which in this case is `LaunchedEffect`

Append your error message with Unix timestamp and then remove the time stamp while displaying the error message in the snack bar.

something like this:

```
errorMessage = errorMessage + System.currentTimeMillis()
LaunchedEffect(errorMessage) {
   if (errorMessage != null) {
        val messageToDisplay = //code to remove the timepstamp 
        scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(messageToDisplay)
   }
}
```