# StateFlow causing navigation loop in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

There are two screens in the app. Screen A and Screen B. The UI and navigation logic of Screen A is based on the state class.

**ScreenAState**

```kotlin
data class ScreenAState(
    val sourceName: String = "",
    val navigateToScreenB: Boolean = false
)
```

If the user meets the requirements, the value of `navigateToScreenB` is changed to `true` and the user is navigated to Screen B using the following code.

```kotlin
if (uiState.navigateToScreenB) {
     LaunchedEffect(uiState.navigateToScreenB) {
          findNavController().navigate(actionToScreenB)
        }
    }
```

Now, the problem occurs when the user presses the back button on Screen B. As soon as the user comes back from Screen B to Screen A, the user is again navigated to Screen B and the loop continues if the back button is pressed again on Screen B.

I am not sure if I am using the `LaunchedEffect` properly. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: @Abhimanyu I did think about that but wasn't sure if that's the recommended approach.

Comment: Try using [DisposableEffect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#disposableeffect)

Comment: I prefer [using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71036376/3585796) shared flow for such operations.

Answer (score 2):

You should set `navigateToScreenB` to false after perform the navigation.
Declaring something like this in your view model.

```
class YourViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(ScreenAState())
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun onNavigateToScreenB() {
        uiState.update {
            it.copy(navigateToScreenB = false)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

and in your screen:

```
val uiState by yourViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
if (uiState.navigateToScreenB) {
    LaunchedEffect(uiState.navigateToScreenB) {
        viewModel.onNavigateToScreenB()
        findNavController().navigate(actionToScreenB)
    }
}
```